# UiView setFrame object

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

On my `Swift` project I'm using `obj-c` frameworks.  So far it works fine, but I'm trying to convert some old code written on `obj-c` to `Swift`.

I managed to translate everything except  this line of code:

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:AR_VIEW_TAG]setFrame:arViewFrame];
```

For any help I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this? I'm assuming AR_VIEW_TAG is an Int...

```
if let selectedView = view.viewWithTag(AR_VIEW_TAG) {
   // Do something with selectedView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
    let myView = self.view.viewWithTag(AR_VIEW_TAG) as UIView?
    myView?.frame = arViewFrame
```